# What's difference between built-in FUNCTION and the FUNCS add-on?

Tags: scope, rebol, rebol3

There is a [new implementation of FUNCTION](http://www.rebol.com/article/0543.html) in Rebol 3, which allows making variables automatically bound to local context by default.

FUNCTION seems to have a problem with the VALUE? test, as it returns TRUE even if a variable has not been set at runtime yet:

```
foo: function [] [
    if value? 'bar [
        print [{Before assignment, bar has a value, and it is} bar]
    ]

    bar: 10

    if value? 'bar [
        print [{After assignment, bar has a value, and it is} bar]
    ]
]
```

If you call FOO you will get:

```
Before assignment, bar has a value, and it is none
After assignment, bar has a value, and it is 10
```

That is not the way FUNC works (it only says BAR has a value after the assignment).  But then FUNC does not make variables automatically local.

I found the FUNCS primitive here, in a library created by Ladislav Mecir.  How is it different, and does it have the same drawbacks?

http://www.fm.vslib.cz/~ladislav/rebol/funcs.r

Comment: As you learn a bit more about Rebol and scoping, you might want to take a second look at Rubol, for instance this test: http://github.com/hostilefork/rubol/blob/master/scope-test.r

Comment: I have re-reread ladislav bindology 10 times and didn't even understand all, I think it'll be the same with yours but I'll try as hard ;)

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is, that FUNCTION deep-searches for set-words in the body, while FUNCS just shallow-searches for them.  FUNCS also uses a slightly different specification.

FUNCS has been around for quite some time (a name change occurred not long ago, though).

That VALUE? function "problem" is related to the fact that the local variables of functions (even if you use FUNC with /LOCAL to explicitly declare them) are initialized to NONE.  That causes the VALUE? function to yield TRUE even when the variables are "not initialized yet".

Generally, I do not see this "initialized with NONE" a "big deal", although this behavior is not the same as the behavior of either global or object variables

Comment: For me it's a big deal because I often want to test optional parameters. Refinement is not always user friendly I prefer to be able to ignore params.

Comment: I am still not sure you understand the VALUE? issue. I wrote the example code supposing you to run it to see what is it about.

Comment: Regarding testing for optional parameters: it is possible anyway.